# Using MLSparse in JMatIO

Tags: java, matlab, sparse-matrix

We're attempting to use JMatio to output a set of Mahout SequentialAccessSparseVectors as a single MLSparse (matrix) in JMatIO for later consumption by MatLab.

*Disclaimer:  I know Java, but I'm a MatLab newbie.*

When we create a MLSparse and populate it with our vectors, calling the MLSparse.contentToString() routine outputs the data as we would expect. However, when it's written to file by MatFileWriter, it shows up having only ONE of the vectors w/in it:

```
int nzRows     = vectors.get(0).getNumNonZeroElements();
int sampleCols = vectors.size();           // MatLab is by-column, so on column/vector
int sampleRows = vectors.get(0).size();    // Rows are the Entries in the vectors
MLSparse matLabMatrix = new MLSparse( "vectors", new int[]{sampleRows, sampleCols}, 0, nzRows * sampleCols );    
mergeSparse( vectors, matLabMatrix );
```

With mergeSparse being:

```
private static void mergeSparse( ArrayList<SequentialAccessSparseVector> vectors, MLSparse destSparse )
{
    int sampleNumber = 0;
    for ( SequentialAccessSparseVector sasv : vectors )   
    { 
        Iterator<Vector.Element> iterator = sasv.iterateNonZero();        
        while ( iterator.hasNext() ) 
        {
            Vector.Element vectorElement = iterator.next();
            int    index = vectorElement.index();
            double value = vectorElement.get();
            destSparse.setReal( value, index, sampleNumber );
        }   
        ++sampleNumber;
    }
}
```

As a contrived example, if our sparse vectors were:  { 1, 2, 3 } { 4, 5, 6 }
calling .contentToString() would yield:

```
vectors =
(0, 0) 1
(1, 0) 2
(2, 0) 3
(0, 1) 4
(1, 1) 5
(2, 1) 6
```

but . . . the file on disk reads as:

```
(0, 0) 1
(1, 0) 2
(2, 0) 3
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally, I find that JMatIO's own test code throws null pointer exceptions:


`MLSparse mlSparse = new MLSparse(name, new int[] {3, 2}, MLArray.mtFLAG_COMPLEX, 5);`
`mlSparse.setReal(1.3, 0, 0);`
`mlSparse.setReal(4.0, 0, 1);`
`mlSparse.setReal(2.0, 1, 0);`
`mlSparse.setImaginary(2.0, 1, 0);`
`mlSparse.setImaginary(6.0, 2, 1);`
``        
`//write array to file`
`ArrayList<MLArray> list = new ArrayList<MLArray>();`
`list.add( mlSparse );`
``        
`//write arrays to file`
`new MatFileWriter( fileName, list );  <-- throws NPE on MatFileWriter.writeMatrix:281`